# Laravel update - Image uploaded file path not stored in database

Tags: database, laravel, controller, eloquent

I have a table with multiple fields as below.

[image: Image Fields]

When I update the form, only **`large_image`** field is updated, **`thumbnail_image`** is not updated.

**My form**

```
<form action="/update', $id)}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" files="true">
<input type="text" name="name">  
<input type="file" name="large_image" multiple="false" accept="image/x-png, image/jpeg">
<input type="file" name="thumb_image" multiple="false" accept="image/x-png, image/jpeg">
<input type="submit">
```

**Model**

```
class Item extends Model {
protected $fillable = ['name', 'large_image', 'thumb_image'];
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function update((Request $request, $id){
$requestData = $request->all();

$item= Item::findOrFail($id);
if ($request->hasFile('large_image')) 
  {
    $fileName = $request->file('large_image')->getClientOriginalName();
    $fileExt = $request->file('large_image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $fullFileName = $fileName.'_'.time().'.'.$fileExt;

    $path = public_path('images');
    Image::make($fileName)->save($path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. $fullFileName);

    $requestData['large_image'] = "images/{$fullFileName}";
    }



    if ($request->hasFile('thumb_image')) 
    {
        $file = $request->file('thumb_image');

        {
            $file_thumb = $request->file('thumb_image')->getClientOriginalName();

            $file_thumb_Ext = $request->file('thumb_image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $fullfile_thumb = $file_thumb.'_'.time().'.'.$filethumb_Ext;

            $path_thumb = public_path('images/thumb');

            Image::make($file)->save($path_thumb . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. $fullfile_thumb);
        }
        $requestData['thumb_image'] = "images/thumb/{$fullfile_thumb}";

    }


   $item->update($requestData);
}
```

What I am missing here? But both images are uploaded and image paths are written in database in create method.

Comment: Going on a limb here, but is it because of the extra accolades (`{` and `}`) in the `if ($request->hasFile('thumb_image)` block? Seems like you can't do that in PHP: https://3v4l.org/rVnWX

Comment: I tried removing that, but not worked. Images are uploaded to ``images/thumb``, but not in databasse.

Comment: change $requestData['large_image'] = "images/{$fullFileName}"; to  $item->large_image = "images/{$fullFileName}"; and then use $item->save();

Comment: Ya, it seemed working. Why this happening? For one image ``$requestData['large_image'] = "images/{$fullFileName}"`` works, why not for ``$requestData['thumb_image'] = "images/{$fullfile_thumb}"``?

Comment: show your model dude!

Comment: @universal -- which one you tried

Comment: @Loek Solution not worked, but Gopi's solution worked. Adam - Question updated with Model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Model**

Replace ***thumb_image*** by ***thumbnail_image*** as you have column name in table ***thumbnail_image***

```
class Item extends Model {
   protected $fillable = ['name', 'large_image', 'thumbnail_image'];
}
```

**Controller**

Same do in controller replace key value ***thumb_image*** by ***thumbnail_image*** as you have column name in table ***thumbnail_image***

Replace

> $requestData['thumb_image']

by

> $requestData['thumbnail_image']

```
public function update((Request $request, $id){
$requestData = $request->all();

$item= Item::findOrFail($id);
if ($request->hasFile('large_image')) 
  {
    $fileName = $request->file('large_image')->getClientOriginalName();
    $fileExt = $request->file('large_image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $fullFileName = $fileName.'_'.time().'.'.$fileExt;

    $path = public_path('images');
    Image::make($fileName)->save($path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. $fullFileName);

    $requestData['large_image'] = "images/{$fullFileName}";
    }



    if ($request->hasFile('thumb_image')) 
    {
        $file = $request->file('thumb_image');

        {
            $file_thumb = $request->file('thumb_image')->getClientOriginalName();

            $file_thumb_Ext = $request->file('thumb_image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $fullfile_thumb = $file_thumb.'_'.time().'.'.$filethumb_Ext;

            $path_thumb = public_path('images/thumb');

            Image::make($file)->save($path_thumb . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. $fullfile_thumb);
        }
        $requestData['thumbnail_image'] = "images/thumb/{$fullfile_thumb}";

    }


   $item->update($requestData);
}
```

Hope this work for you.

Comment: did u find solution?

Comment: Do changes in model:
protected $fillable = ['name', 'large_image', 'thumbnail_image'];

Do changes in controller:
$requestData['thumbnail_image']

You have used column name "thumbnail_image" and passing key name in controller and column name in model is "thumb_image".

Answer (score 0):

Your model is:

```
class Item extends Model {
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'large_image', 'thumb_image'];
}
```

Look now at your database, the column name is different, so model should look like this:

```
class Item extends Model {
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'large_image', 'thumbnail_image'];
}
```

Good luck!